# No main class in small Java program + embedding as applet

Tags: java, web, applet

I'm having an issue with my code. Specifically this. When I compile it in Netbeans it says " Could not find or load main class Form" but I see it right in the code...what am I doing incorrectly?

Second of all, to embed it on a web page could I compile it and do ? Thank you for your help. I'm only a week into Java GUI stuff.

```
package gui;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

class Form {
    private static void display() {
        JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field3 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field4 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field5 = new JTextField();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Username:"));
        panel.add(field1);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
        panel.add(field2);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Repeat Password:"));
        panel.add(field3);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Email address:"));
        panel.add(field4);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Repeat email address:"));
        panel.add(field5);
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Form",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an applet? In that case please look into the following link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html

Answer (score 0):

Make your class public and the main method will be found and run properly.